# How can I access the table that holds GROUPS in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, security, web, oracle-apex

How to access table that holds the workspace groups information? I need a SQL method of accessing that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at APEX_WORKSPACE_GROUPS and APEX_WORKSPACE_GROUP_USERS. I believe these are only available from Apex 4.1 on though.

In older versions you need to (try to) access the tables wwv_flow_fnd_group_users and wwv_flow_fnd_user_groups.  You would probably need to add grants on these tables to see them.

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Yeah...corporate bureaucracy...no permissions to these tables. Going to have to fake the grouping functionality by creating my own table in my namespace.